# Sequences that are bounded, but converge pointwise to an unbounded sequence and vice versa.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm very bad in coming up with examples and I was asked if there can be sequences that are bounded, but converge pointwise to an unbounded sequence and vice versa.

For the first one I thought that if I just let $f_n(x)=g(x) \chi_{[-n,n]}(x)$, then shouldn't this work for any unbounded function $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$? Are there any other simple examples that I could demonstrate without the usage of the indicator function?

For the other part I couldn't figure out an example so I would be happy to see one!

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about sequences of *bounded functions* that converge pointwise to an *unbounded* function, correct? The title and the first sentence of the post are somewhat confusingly written.

Comment: Also, for the example in your post, you need to truncate the vertical height of the function, as opposed to its horizontal width to get a sequence of bounded functions. Something like $f_n = \min(n,|g|)$. When $|g|>n$, $f_n = n$ and when $|g| \le n$, $f_n = g$. This ensures each $f_n$ is bounded by $n$, and the limit is $|g|$, which is unbounded by assumption. Unless your question is about functions with bounded *support*. An edit to the title and body of the question to make things clearer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part consider $\{f_n\}$ where each $f_n\colon (0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is given by
$$
f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
n & 0<x\leq\frac{1}{n}\\
1/x & \frac{1}{n}<x
\end{cases}
$$
We have that $f_n\to 1/x$ pointwise. Clearly every $f_n$ is bounded, but the limit function is not.

Now, if for the other part you mean a sequence of unbounded functions that converges pointwise to a bounded function consider $\{f_n \}$ given by $f_n(x)=x/n$ which converges pointwise to $f(x)=0$.